# TypeScript and NodeJS Project Configuration

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm new to nodeJS and as I studying TypeScript I begin to embrace. My problem is how to configure/organize a project. Is there any way to configure a project in TypeScript and NodeJS without using gulp, or any other third party library.

Comment: Choose some [compiler options](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), then use them [in a file tsconfig.json](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my way to create a new project with Node.js and TypeScript from scratch. Assuming you have already installed TypeScript and Node.js.

Firstly, create a new folder for your project.

Open the command line which points to your project folder, type `npm init`.
The command will ask you some questions relate to your Node.js project. After finishing, a file named `package.json` will be created in your project folder.

To create TypeScript `tsconfig.json` file, you can type `tsc --init` from the command line which points to your project folder. You can then modify `tsconfig.json` file as you want.